# Match words in array line by line to a separate file

Tags: linux, bash, array, csv

Here is a sample of my input data:

```
$9.99,Titan the Power,www.example.com,565654
$15.99,Conan The Barbarian,www.sure.com,565438
$1.99,Julia Cesar,www.bfg.com,69722
```

I have written this code so that I create an array from the input file, and then isolate the title with the `$f2` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/home/test/Documents/Scripts/test.csv"

readarray myarray < $input    

# Sends all of arrays into while loop which read each line by line
echo "${myarray[@]}" | while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4
do
  # echo field 2 of each line
  echo $f2 #This displays the title of each product (just for testing)
done
```

Now I would like to compare each title (`$f2`) with another file (`$csv2`) to see if there are any positive matches.

csv2:

```
$1.99,The Power of Now,www.dvd.com,45674
$9.99,Titan the Power,www.otherwebsite.com,13357
$2.99,The incredible Hulk,www.purchase.com,13956
```

I know that I can compare files with something like this:

```
if [ "$f2" == "$csv2" ]; then
  echo "match"
fi
```

The above code matches the whole thing, and lines in `csv2` are likely to be in a different order and contain other stuff which I'm not interested in. I want the script to inform me of only the lines from `$f2` which have matching titles in `csv2`. So the output might look something like this if only the first title was present in `csv2`:

```
Matching lines:

$9.99,Titan the Power,www.otherwebsite.com,13357
$9.99,Titan the Power,www.example.com,565654
```

I would like the original line and the matching line to be displayed as the output so I can compare them, like above (notice other field values are slightly different between `$input` and `$csv2` but title is the same).

Comment: Unless you're doing this for strictly pedagogical reasons, I'd suggest using awk/perl/python (or a standard utility such as `join`) for this - rather than pure shell programming

Comment: He's mentioned that the lines won't necessarily be in the same order, which means join might miss some matches unless he sorts both files first, adding complexity.  What's wrong with shell script?  This can be done with relatively simple grep.

Comment: csv2 data added

Comment: This kind of question has been asked and answered so many times (I don't have the time to search for the duplicates but there should be about a dozen of them)... Here's a very simple `awk` one liner that should do: `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{x[$2]=$0;next};$2 in x{print;print x[$2]}' csv1 csv2`

Comment: good solution don, that is working

Comment: Is there any way I can modify that line to create a positive match, for lets say, 3 or more matching words (i.e. all words don't have to match but if 3 or more do then the same result is acheived?

Comment: Basically a cross-site duplicate of. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272717/inner-join-on-two-text-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get all the titles from your first file with something like

```
interesting_titles=$(cat $input |cut -d, -f2)
```

then use that to grep your second file for those titles

```
grep -F "$interesting_titles" $csv2
```

Anything returned by grep would be a match.

You can shorten this to a one-liner with

```
grep -F "$(cat $input |cut -d, -f2)" $csv2
```

If you want the output from both files side-by-side you probably want a for loop, like....

```
cat $input |cut -d, -f2 | while read t; do
  grep -i "$t" $csv2
  if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    grep -i "$t" $input
  fi
done
```

This will loop over each line in $input, check for and print that record in $csv2 in $input

Comment: Thanks smokes2345, that's working nicely, I just need one more thing which  I forgot, and I hope is an easy amendment- I need the original line from $input and the matching title line form $csv2 to be displayed as the output- I've edited my question.

Comment: Hi smokes, i've run the script and the output is longer than expected and contains some of the data which doesn't match, this is the output:

Comment: $9.99,Titan the Power,www.otherwebsite.com,13357
$9.99,Titan the Power,www.example.com,565654
$9.99,Titan the Power,www.otherwebsite.com,13357
$9.99,Titan the Power,www.example.com,565654
$1.99,The Power of Now,www.dvd.com,45674
$9.99,Titan the Power,www.otherwebsite.com,13357
$9.99,Titan the Power,www.example.com,565654
$1.99,The Power of Now,www.dvd.com,45674
$2.99,The incredible Hulk,www.purchase.com,13956
$15.99,Conan The Barbarian,www.sure.com,565438

Comment: effing spaces, fixed the script

Comment: brilliant, that's worked! Could you explain what the if [ $? -eq 0 ] bit does? cheers for your help

Comment: It checks the return code of grep.  grep returns 0 when it finds a match in $csv2 and the shell then runs the same search on $input to get the corresponding line in that file

Comment: I also added the "-i" flag so capitalization won't matter under the assumption that capitalization doesn't matter to you.